# Display dynamic content wrap around a image

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Plz suggest me how i bind the content in asp.net c#. The content is dynamic and that will wrap around the image.And also how i can display

Comment: Please provide code examples, and be more specific about the programming issue you are having

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your markup place your image and use a Literal control

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Sample.png" />
<asp:Literal ID="PlaceHolderLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

In your code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            String DynamicText = "<p>Your dynamic text to be rendered.</p><p>Your next dynamic text to be rendered.</p>";
            DynamicText += "<p>Your additional dynamic text to be rendered.</p>";
            PlaceHolderLiteral.Text = DynamicText;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks Mr. AntLaC it works.My content(Dynamic) is large so i want to display in a paragraph with proper space and new line.How it possible.

Comment: I have editied my answer to demonstrate. You can use standard HTML mark up in your string. You can also build your string from a datasource. So, you are not limited there.